# Rhino merge two compiled Scripts into one

Tags: java, android, rhino

I am using Rhino in Java to execute JavaScript on Android.
To execute the javascript I create a Script object by using Context#compileString()
and then later calling exec on the script object.

The executed js I call consists of two parts: One is constant and one is dynamic. Is it possible to compile the constant part only once to increase performance? I couldn't find anything on merging two script objects, so it seems that this is not possible. But maybe I just overlooked something or there is another approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use a [ScriptContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptContext.html), and you get it from your [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#getContext%28%29) and then [eval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval%28java.lang.String,%20javax.script.ScriptContext%29) it again. Note that you can reuse it (as long as you don't modify the static part), see `compiled` below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
  ScriptEngine rhino = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
  try {
    rhino.eval("function f(){return 1+1;} "
        + "function g(){return f()*f();}");
    ScriptContext compiled = rhino.getContext();
    String f = rhino.eval("f()", compiled).toString();
    String g = rhino.eval("g()", compiled).toString();
    System.out.println("f() = " + f);
    System.out.println("g() = " + g);
  } catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The output is

```
f() = 2.0
g() = 4.0
```

**Edit**

Note, I could also have done -

```
rhino.eval("var i = 0; function f(){return ++i;} "
      + "function g(){return f()*f();}");
ScriptContext compiled = rhino.getContext();
String f = rhino.eval("f()", compiled).toString();
System.out.println("f() = " + f);
f = rhino.eval("f()", compiled).toString();
String g = rhino.eval("g()", compiled).toString();
System.out.println("f() = " + f);
System.out.println("g() = " + g);
```

Which outputs (the perhaps unexpected) 12,

```
f() = 1.0
f() = 2.0
g() = 12.0
```